# 2 weeks or fortnight per page in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, ssrs-grouping

I have records for 3 weeks that needs to be displayed on an SSRS report 2 weeks per page. So my report would have 2 pages - first 2 weeks in the first page and 3rd week in the second page. How do I do this with a grouping expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, have a column(in your query or stored procedure) that indicates the fortnight period.

For example, let the column name be FortnightPeriod,
which can contain values like 1st fortnight, 2nd fortnight.

Then group by that column in your rdl and add page breaks for the group.

Comment: Thanks mate..That worked..I was trying to do it in the RDL which seems impossible..